# Limiting table rows (BIP)

Tags: xml, oracle, rtf, bi-publisher

Using RTF and BI Publisher, I have a long table and I want to show only 10 rows on each page. How to do that?
As far as I did is:

1. After grouping defining some variables:

   ```
   <?xdoxslt:set_variable($_XDOCTX, ‘counter’, 0)?>
   <?xdoxslt:set_variable($_XDOCTX, ‘lines_page’, 16)?>
   <?xdoxslt:set_variable($_XDOCTX, ‘tot_lines’, count(.//A.U_VATX))?>
   ```
2. Inside the cell of first column:

   ```
   <?xdoxslt:set_variable($_XDOCTX, ‘counter’,xdoxslt:get_variable($_XDOCTX, ‘counter’)+1)?>
   <?if@inlines:xdoxslt:get_variable($_XDOCTX,’counter’) != xdoxslt:get_variable($_XDOCTX,’tot_lines’)?>
   <?if@inlines:position() mod xdoxslt:get_variable($_XDOCTX, ‘lines_page’) = xdoxslt:get_variable($_XDOCTX,’lines_page’)-1?><?call:footer?><?end if?>
   <?if@inlines:position() mod xdoxslt:get_variable($_XDOCTX, ‘lines_page’) = 0?><?call:breaking?><?end if?><?end if?>
   ```
3. After table, defining the templates:

   ```
   <?template:footer?>
   table cell with data
   <?end template?>
   <?call-template:footer?>
   <?template:breaking?> 
     table cell empty
     <?split-by-page-break:?> 
     <?end template?>
   ```
4. End

Comment: If you really want someone to help, you need to post more information like your sample markup you have tried.

Comment: Do you have the option of editing your SQL / Data Definition?